# My current tires on my hybrid bike are 700 x 40. Can i drop bown to 700 x 38 or 700 x 35?

Tags: tire

I have a diamondback parkway that can use new tires. The are 700 x 40. The availability of this size is limited.  Can I drop down to a 700x38 or 700x35?

Comment: Welcome to the site - please don't be offended that this question is closed as a duplicate, it is a common question that gets asked periodically.  Read the linked question and apply it to your situation.  Ultimately the answer is "probably yes" but measure to be sure.   You can also read the [tour] to learn more about how the SE sites work, as Q&A.